# Is this Java class has visibility risk or thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

The main purpose of the class is to act like an Event Bus, multiple thread can register/unregister model through it.

```
public class ThreadSafeHash {
    private final HashMap<String, LinkedList<Model>> modelMap = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean addModel(final String category, final Model model) {
        LinkedList<Model> categoryContents = modelMap.get(category);
        if (categoryContents == null) {
            categoryContents = new LinkedList<>();
            modelMap.put(category, categoryContents);
        }

        synchronized (categoryContents) {
            return categoryContents.add(model);
        }
    }

    public boolean removeModel(final Model model) {
        LinkedList<Model> categoryContents = modelMap.get(model.getCategory());
        if (categoryContents == null) {
            return false;
        }

        synchronized (categoryContents) {
            return categoryContents.remove(model);
        }
    }
}
```

The main doubt is that multiple threads may put a list to the `modelMap` but this action is not synchroized, will this introduce visibility risk?

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Yes, `ConcurrentHashMap` is the right way to implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not thread safe because access to `modelMap` is not synchronized - but not because of visibility.

In the `addModel` method, two threads could both detect `modelMap.get(category) == null`, and so they would both put a new `LinkedList` into the map - one would stomp the other, so you would lose the `model` instance added in the first of those threads.

This happens because the "add if not present" check is not atomic; not that the updates are not visible.

Comment: Ok, if we synchronize on the `modelMap` for both `addModel` and `removeModel` , and further add a `getModelMapSize` method but without any synchronization, will it has visibility risk? This frustration is lead by the `java.util.Observable#countObservers` method.

Comment: You have multiple threads, at least one of which makes structural changes to the map and lists. As such, you need to synchronize *all* access to those, per the javadoc (including in `getModelMapSize`). Synchronization gives you happens-before, so you should not have visibility issues then.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: This solution works only for Java 8 or higher**

In addition I would suggest using `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(..)` method here, which returns a value by a key if it's present and computes and returns a new value (`new LinkedList<>()` in your case) if there is no such value mapped to the key. The whole method is atomic and if you use `Collections.synchronizedList()` on a LinkedList it will make the synchronized block unnecessary.

```
public class ThreadSafeHash {

private final ConcurrentMap<String, List<Model>> modelMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public boolean addModel(final String category, final Model model) {
      List<Model> categoryContents = modelMap.computeIfAbsent(
          category,
          k -> Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());
      return categoryContents.add(model);
}

public boolean removeModel(final Model model) {
    List<Model> categoryContents = modelMap.get(model.getCategory());
    return categoryContents != null && categoryContents.remove(model);
}

}
```

Also note that the API of your `ThreadSafeHash` class gives a chance for it's user to make it inconsistent. If someone provides a wrong category for a model in the `addModel(..)` method, then the model never be removed, because `removeModel(..)` relies on `model.getCategory()`.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is not thread-safe and that class is not thread safe because its access is not synchronised.

Bear in mind that even using a ConcurrentHashMap won't give you 100% "safety" against concurrency issues because the "pufIfAbsent" behaviour, provided by *categoryContents == null* and *categoryContents = new LinkedList<>()* then *modelMap.put(category, categoryContents)*, is not atomic in any case.

[ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V))